# Setup a subdomain with s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have purchased my domain from `GoDaddy` and using below `AWS` services to host the files:

1. S3
2. CloudFront
3. Route 53
4. IAM
5. Lambda
6. SNS
7. SES

For example, I am using `domain.com`. I have created a new **S3 bucket** and upload a single `index.html` file into that bucket. Now I want to **create a new subdomain `v2.domain.com`** and point that domain to my newly created bucket.

How can I setup?

Answer (score 1):

Your Fully Qualified Subdomain name must be the same as the S3 bucket name. So in Your case bucket name will be **subdomainv2.domain.com**

Once you name a new bucket as per your Sub Domain naming convention, you will have S3 URL assigned to it that looks something like [http://subdomainv2.domain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.](https://subdomainv2.domain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.)

Now Next thing you need to do is to your domain host and map your subdomain to the URL from above step. where a  mapping the host "subdomainv2" to the address "subdomainv2.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" as a **CNAME record**.

You can also refer the following URL: [Alias a Domain and Sub Domain S3 configuration](https://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3/)

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is making a sense. Can you please give me any detailed reference?

Comment: try following link: https://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3/